# "Cost management data is unavailable for subscription" AZURE cost usage API

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to retrieve Azure cost data for the management group using azure cost usage API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage

But Im getting below error.

"Cost management data is unavailable for subscription xxxxxxxxxxx. The offer MS-AZR-xxxxP is not supported. (Request ID: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx)"

Request URL
https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2019-11-01&$top=5000

**Is there any way to skip such subsciptions and get data for supported subscriptions using above API.Please assist.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason you may be seeing this message is because Azure Cost Management is not supported for all [`Azure Offer types`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/support/legal/offer-details/).

Please check this link for supported/unsupported Azure Offer types for Azure Cost Management: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/understand-cost-mgt-data#supported-microsoft-azure-offers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes i understand that. is there any way to skip those subscriptions using above API?

Comment: You can capture this error for unsupported subscriptions and move onto next subscriptions. Right?

Comment: Nope. This endpoint doesn't give any cost data regarding to any subscriptions because one or two subscriptions has this offer type issue.